# Different appearance between Firefox and Chrome of the Border style

Tags: css, border

Codes as below. I'm so puzzled of this problem.

```
table td{
    padding:10px;
    background:#415DA1;
    border-top:solid 10px #F00;
    border-right:solid 10px #CCC;
    border-bottom:solid 10px #F00;
    border-left:solid 10px #CCC;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The apperance between Firefox and Chrome has some differences, I'm not sure if it's coused by the differences of different brwosers. Is there any way to fix it by CSS?

> **Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/B2fjn/**

Comment: Important note - jsfiddle.net adds `border-collapse: collapse` to tables. Without this, it is impossible to reproduce the problem in separate document.

Comment: @duri: I added the fiddle.  It's true, jsFiddle adds a CSS reset. However, with `separate` as the value the borders look the same in Firefox and Chrome, so I suspect the fiddle is a true representation of the OP's problem. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just differing border drawing implementations.  You'll notice that there's a difference in IE and Opera too:

[image]

I didn't test Safari, but I'd expect it to look the same as Chrome since they use the same rendering engine.

The only way that I can think of to get a consistent border across browsers is to set `border-collapse` to `separate` on the `<table>` element:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

This, unfortunately, means you have a new problem to solve — there will now be *2x* `10px` borders between each cell. You can work around this by altering your markup or adding extra CSS rules.  For instance, I changed the CSS to the following:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}

table td{
    padding:10px;
    background:#415DA1;
    border-top:solid 10px #F00;
    border-right:solid 5px #CCC;
    border-bottom:solid 10px #F00;
    border-left:solid 5px #CCC;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left-width: 10px;
}
table td:last-child {
    border-right-width: 10px;
}
```

> **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/B2fjn/1/**

This gives as good a result as you can probably expect in modern browsers, but doesn't look so great in IE 6-8.  You'll need to experiment until you can get the best result possible.

Comment: Awesome!! I think this is caused by the differences of different browses. Maybe I should learn the border rendering of different browses first. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax for border (css) is : `border: 1px solid #FFF;`.
Now, change your CSS like this:

```
table tr td{
    padding:10px;
    background:#415DA1;
    border-top:10px solid #F00;
    border-right:10px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom:10px solid #F00;
    border-left:10px solid #CCC;
}
```

Some browsers have the ability to correct the css code if there's any problem ( like yours ), but some don't. So, please check if the new CSS code works or not. If it doesn't, please post the screenshots of both the browsers displaying the document. Thank You.

Comment: This isn't the problem - all the current major browsers are lenient enough to allow these values in any order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that this is coused by the different "border" rendering methods of different browses. I have changed my codes as your example, the problem is still there.(I haven't the authority to upload image now... so sorry).

Answer (score 0):

In my case that border problem create offset between elements in Firefox.

Solution: add this css rules to your bordered element.

```
div{
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  ...
}
```